# Service starts on boot when it should not

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have a toggle, when clicked a notification with battery level starts. This is a service that register a broadcast receiver. When the toggle is in `false` state the notification disappear. Well, even if the state is false if i boot the device the notification, so the service, starts. I can't understand the problem but i i saw in the logCat that when i turn off the toggle it displays this error:

```
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337): Service com.dd.androreboot.NotificationService has leaked IntentReceiver com.dd.androreboot.NotificationService$1@44eecef0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.dd.androreboot.NotificationService has leaked IntentReceiver com.dd.androreboot.NotificationService$1@44eecef0 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:805)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:606)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1430)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1410)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1404)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:467)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at com.dd.androreboot.NotificationService.onCreate(NotificationService.java:105)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2572)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-18 14:15:03.149: E/ActivityThread(337):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could be the problem? This is the service:

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
    public static final int FM_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    public static int SHOW_TEMP = 1; // whether to show temperature in status bar
    public static int SHOW_HEALTH = 1; // whether to show battery health in status bar
    public static int SHOW_VOLTAGE = 1; // whether to show voltage in status bar
    public static int SHOW_VOLTAGE_MILLIVOLT = 1; // whether to show millivolts in status bar
    public static int SHOW_STATUS = 1; // whether to show Charging/Not Charging, etc
    public static int SHOW_PERIODIC_TOASTS = 10; // whether to show periodic toast messages with charge level

    @Override 
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
          return null;
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unused" })
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
            int temp = intent.getIntExtra("temperature", 0) / 10;
            int voltage = intent.getIntExtra("voltage", 0);
            int status = intent.getIntExtra("status", BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_UNKNOWN);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra("scale", -1);
            int health = intent.getIntExtra("health", -1);
            boolean isPresent = intent.getBooleanExtra("present", false);
            String strStatus;
            String strHealth = "Health: ";

            // Calculate level
            if (level >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                level = (level * 100) / scale;
            }

            if(SHOW_PERIODIC_TOASTS == 10){
                Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(level + "%"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // Determine battery status         
            switch(status){
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING : strStatus = getResources().getString(R.string.charging); break;
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_DISCHARGING : strStatus = getResources().getString(R.string.discharging); break;
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_NOT_CHARGING : strStatus = getResources().getString(R.string.discharging); break;
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL : strStatus = "Full"; break;
                default : strStatus = "Status Unknown";
            }


            // Determine battery health
            switch(health){
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_COLD : strHealth += "Cold"; break;
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_DEAD : strHealth += "Dead"; break;
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_GOOD : strHealth += "Good"; break;
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVERHEAT : strHealth += "Overheat"; break;
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_OVER_VOLTAGE : strHealth += "Over Voltage"; break;
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNKNOWN : strHealth += "Unknown"; break;
                case BatteryManager.BATTERY_HEALTH_UNSPECIFIED_FAILURE : strHealth += "Unspc Failure"; break;
                default : strStatus = "Health Unknown";
            }

            // The initial call out notification
            String NotificationTicket = getResources().getString(R.string.notifistart);

            // The status user sees upon pulling notification bar down
            String NotificationTitle = level + "%";
            if(SHOW_STATUS == 1){ NotificationTitle += " "+ getResources().getString(R.string.and) +" " + strStatus; }

            // The content show underneath the battery percentage
            String NotificationContent = "";
            if(SHOW_TEMP == 1) { NotificationContent += temp + "°C  "; }
            if(SHOW_VOLTAGE == 1) {
                if(SHOW_VOLTAGE_MILLIVOLT == 1){
                    NotificationContent += voltage + "mV  ";
                } else {
                    NotificationContent += voltage / 1000 + "V  ";
                }
            }
            if(SHOW_HEALTH == 1) { NotificationContent += strHealth; }

            Bitmap largeIcon = (Bitmap)BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.notification);

            addNotification(NotificationTitle, NotificationContent, NotificationTicket, largeIcon, level);
        }
    }; 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() {
          super.onCreate();
          this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {         
          Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.notifistop), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          removeNotification();
          super.onDestroy();
    }

    // Start notification
    private void addNotification(String title, String body, String ticker, Bitmap largeIcon, int iconLevel) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =  
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)  
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.levellist, iconLevel)
                .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                .setContentTitle(title)  
                .setContentText(body)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setNumber(iconLevel)
                .setTicker(ticker);  

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainNavDrawer.class);  
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,   
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);  
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);  

        // Add as notification  
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  
        manager.notify(FM_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());  
    }  

    // Remove notification  
    private void removeNotification() {  
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);  
        manager.cancel(FM_NOTIFICATION_ID);  
    }  
}
```

The 105 line is:

```
this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

Comment: When you are done with your service/activity and no more need `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` broadcasts, you should call `unregisterReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver)`

Comment: In `onDestroy` or where exactly?

Comment: i wrote `unregisterReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver);` in `onDestroy`.. no more errors but after boot the notification shows again!

Answer (score 0):

For **Service:** 
You should unregister the reciever in onDestroy()

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver);
   }
```

For **Activity:**
Register the reciever in onResume()

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }
```

You should unregister the reciever in onpause()

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(mBatInfoReceiver);
   }
```

Comment: Why in onPause and not in onDestroy method?

Comment: How can i call the `mBatInfoReceiver` from the service to activity?

Comment: The problem is that the notification starts always on boot.. i tryied using the sharedpreferences of the toggle button; On boot completed i call a broadcastreceiver (AutoStartReceiver) that starts the service. but doesn't work.. i passed the `tgpref` value of the preferences but nothing.. Now doesn't starts after boot.. Only if i open the application

Comment: @David_D actually what you need exactly? whether you need to start the service on boot or you need to continuously run the service for particular time like 3 sec,5min,...